# Why iPhone developer cetificates expire date display error as 1999 ？？

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a newbie iOS developers.I just encountered a stranger problem,which described as the picture above.My iPhone certificates' expire date were all displaying error.I was sure that my Mac OS system date was OK.However how it happened.I'd searched google for a long time,reimport certificates again seemed not work as well.Do you have some ideas???Many thx.

For my points is low,I couldn't embed it in my question content.I put the image  hyperlink of skydrive below.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9CD79309737D6AD1!52644&authkey=!AA4Xsg9-1MbxKYY&v=3

Comment: better post this type of questions related to apple/ios in http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try to reset the keychain http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1544

Comment: I'd reset the keychain,but it still did not works.All the certificates  contains the system's date were displaying 1999.

Comment: Solved it.The reason is that when my friend created the keychain Access in one user whose os system time using default 1999 year,then he created another user and set the right os system time.However the certificates expires still displayed error.I am not sure whether it is a bug in Mac OS 10.8.